# Check if number matches one of a series of numbers with javascript

Tags: javascript

Looking for a way to create a function that lets a user type in their postcode and displays info dependent on if the number is in a list or not.

A optimal solution would be if it could be numbers between 90000-90100 or specific like 90210 or 90212.

HTML

```
<input id="input" type="text">
<input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="postcode()">
<div style="display: none;" id="yes">yes</div>
<div style="display: none;" id="no">no</div>
```

Javascript

```
<script>
function postcode()
{
var input = document.getElementById("input");
if(input.value == "90210"){
    document.getElementById("yes").style.display = "block"
}
else{
    document.getElementById("no").style.display = "block"}
}
</script>
```

Codepen
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rGJOyV

Thank you!

Comment: where is the list stored?

Comment: to check if some item is in a list(array), check if list.indexOf(item) > -1

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
function postcode()
{
var input = document.getElementById("input"),
    value = parseInt(input.value); // From string makes number

if (value > 9000 && value < 90100){
    document.getElementById("yes").style.display = "block"
}
else {
    document.getElementById("no").style.display = "block"}
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks you. Is it a way to check a range of numbers, and a series of specific numbers? Like 90000-91000 and 6001 and not 6002-9000?

Comment: Yes, you can! You need to make validation function which returns true or false like so:

Comment: `if( validate(value) ) {//yes} else {//no};
function validate(value) {

if(value >= 90000 && value <= 91000){return true}
else if(// you can provide infinite checks)
else {return false};
}`

Comment: Excellent @maksims! Another question: Is it possible to write all these numbers in a format as fx. 100,201,302 ?

Comment: Please give me pluss on comment so I reach 50 points, that will allow me to comment questions. :)
To do that You need for loop: for(var i = 1; i <= 10; i++){array += i*100+(i-1)}; // array = [100, 201, 302, etc.];

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manually checking that information with JavaScript, you should try to use standard form validation for your fields, and then, if you need to execute any JS code, just check `myInput.isValid()` method for validity.

There are many ways for form validation: if you just need a number in a range you can use `min` and `max` attributes, but if you need more complex validation, you should go for regular expressions.

Here you have a lot of documentation about how to do form validation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by if condition

```
<script>
function postcode()
{
var input = document.getElementById("input").value;
    var data= parseInt(input); 
if(data>= 90000 && data <= 90100){
    document.getElementById("yes").style.display = "block";
}
else{
    document.getElementById("no").style.display = "block";
}
</script>
```

here we check condition either equal to or greater than 90000 and less than or equal to 90100.

so specific data like 90050 or 90062 fall between them.

Comment: Thanks you @alok. Is it a way to check a range of numbers, and a series of specific numbers? Like 90000-91000 and 6001 and not 6002-9000?